# Script errors while browsing websites using WebBrowser

Tags: c#, javascript, wpf, browser, webbrowser-control

I'm writing a simple web browser and I get some script errors the doesn't occur when I display those sites using IE9.

I know how to suppress these errors but I want to prevent them.

For example, when I try to brows [Jango](http://www.jango.com) and click "play", I get the following message:

[image]

Can someone tell me what is the problem and how can I solve it?

In my code I set the following settings:

```
        private void WebBrowser_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = this;
        webBrowser1.AllowWebBrowserDrop = false;
        webBrowser1.IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled = false;
        webBrowser1.WebBrowserShortcutsEnabled = false;
        webBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = this;
        webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = false;
        //SuppressScriptErrorsOnly(this.webBrowser1);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;` ?

Comment: "I know how to suppress these errors but I want to prevent them." - it prevents the error from being displayed but doesn't solve the problem or allow allows me to play music

Comment: You can set FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION registry flag for you application to use IE9 mode